# Can I do in c++ something more than just 'x++', or 'x--'?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I made here a program to do 3x+1 math problem. So I am asking, if I could write in a c++ code something like `x/2;`, or `x*3+1`. These stuff what i put here are with mistakes. Then, is it possible in c++ to do that? If yes, how?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Write an integer.\n"; int x; cin >> x;
    // I made here a program to do 3x+1 math problem.
    while (x==1)  {
        if ((x%2)==0)  {
            x/2; cout << x << ", ";
        }  else if ((x%2)==1)  {
            x*3+1; cout << x << ", ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output there was:

```
/tmp/GjudkYOaE4.o
Write an integer.
9
```

But I was waiting it to write the number 28, 14, and more, but it did nothing.

Comment: Because you will only enter in while loop when your `x` is equal to `1`

Comment: I suggest [getting a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You need to learn the basics before tackling problems.

Comment: You said ` I was waiting ... 28, 14, and more,` untill when? what is the terminating condition?

Comment: Well, the loop that contains all of your logic runs `while (x==1)`. Is this condition satisfied when you input 9? or 28? or 14?

Comment: This math problem is called the _Collatz conjecture_.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=` operators (and a bunch of others). But no, there's no operator that would directly mean `x=3*x+1`. You'll have to spell it out as I did.

Comment: `x/2` doesn't mutate `x`, but "return" the computation (which you don't use, so discarded), you probably want `x = x / 2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give value to the same variable with assignment operator ('='):

```
x = x*3+1;
```

or

```
x = x/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are new to coding, I would suggest you to please read a good amount of information about `if-elseif-else` and `while loop` that you are using

I can show you a few corrections here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Write an integer.\n"; 
    int x; cin >> x;
    // I made here a program to do 3x+1 math problem.
    while (x!=1)  {                   // x!=1 could be one of the terminating condition so when your x becomes 1, the loop would end. But of course the terminating condition depends on what you are trying to achieve
        if (x % 2 == 0)  {
            x = x/2;                   //you need to assign the value back to x
            cout << x << ", ";
        }  else {                      // you dont need else-if here because there could only be 2 possibilities for %2 operaion here
            x = x*3+1; 
            cout << x << ", ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 3x+1 problem, known as Collatz conjecture, indeed has `x==1` as the terminating condition.

Comment: yes I agree, so in while loop you would need to write `x!=1` to keep the loop going. and as it becomes `x==1` the loop terminates

Comment: Yeah, but the comment is inconsistent with this.

Comment: @RC0993 theoretically it can be an infinite loop since int size is implementation-defined and it is possible to have a loop in Collatz (or prove me wrong ;) ). I mean it is checked for every number which is lower than 2^68, but there is still a possibility.